# jquery selectors not working when used with # for id, but working with div[id="theid"]

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

here is the situation the html

```
<div id="editUser-0" style="display: none;">
    <form action="/admin/uactions.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="userEditorForm-0">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="edituser" />
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="name">Име</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text"  id="name-0" name="name" class="validate[required]" placeholder="Име" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group" >
        <label class="control-label" for="email-0">Имейл</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="email-0" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" name="email" placeholder="Имейл" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="type-0" >Тип</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select name="type" id="type-0">
                <option value="1" >Администратор</option>
                <option value="100" >Потребител</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group hidden" id="avatarWarper-0">
        <label class="control-label" for="avatar-0">Снимка</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar-0" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="typeinvestor-0">Тип инвеститор</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select name="typeinvestor" id="typeinvestor-0" >
                <option value="0">-</option>
                <option value="1">Investor type 1</option>
                <option value="2">Investor type 2</option>
                <option value="3">Investor type 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="phone-0" >Телефон</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="phone-0" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон" class="validate[required]" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="country-0">Държава</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select name="country" id="country-0" class="validate[required]">
                <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and here is the javascript

```
function editUser(id) {
  title = "Change user";
  if (id === 0)
    title = 'New user';

  $('<div>' + $('#editUser-' + id).html() + '</div>').dialog({
    modal: true,
    width: 450,
    title: title,
    buttons: {
      'Save': function() {

        $('#userEditorForm-'+id).validationEngine('attach',{promptPosition : "inline", scroll: true});

        if($('#userEditorForm-'+id).validationEngine('validate')){
          $('#userEditorForm-'+id).submit();
        }

      },
      'Cancel': function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        return false;
      }
    },
    open: function(event, ui) {
       $('.ui-dialog :button').blur();
      $("select[id='type-"+id+"']").click(function(){
        if($(this).val()==1){
          $("div[id='avatarWarper-"+id+"']").removeClass('hidden');
        }else{
           $("div[id='avatarWarper-"+id+"']").addClass('hidden');
        }
      });
     $('#type-'+id).click();
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {

      $(this).dialog('destroy');
      $(this).remove();

    }
  });
}
```

the problem is, when i use `$("div[id='avatarWarper-"+id+"']").click(function(){})` it works but when i try to use  `$("#avatarWarper-"+id).click(function(){});` and this is only when in the open event of the dialog, but for example the submit and validate works both ways.

Comment: Is $("#avatarWarper-0").click(function(){}); also not working for you?

Comment: yes  $("#avatarWarper-0").click(function(){}); is not working, but when i use  $("div[id='avatarWarper-"+id+"']").click(function(){}) is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("div[id='avatarWarper-"+id+"']")
```

and

```
$("#avatarWarper-"+id)
```

are both absolutely valid and look *nearly* equal but significantly differ in one point:

The first returns a set of Elements with ID `'avatarWarper-"+id` while the latter gives you the *first* Element in the DOM with the given ID.

So the only error I could think if is that you assigned this ID to more than one elements in the dom (which is not allowed in terms of valid HTML but wont throw any obvious error).

Comment: oo yes i haven't thought if that i have only one id but when i create the dialog i clone the html and insert it into the modal, which creates two elements with id type-0.

Comment: If it helps, I created a JS Fiddle.  This is the broken version: http://jsfiddle.net/digitaleagle/BHHVG/  and this is the fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/digitaleagle/BHHVG/3/

Comment: hm, `/3` looks rather broken to me, after one cancel the popup does not reappear.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a copy of the `#editUser-*`'s content ending up with invalid markup.

```
$('<div>' + $('#editUser-' + id).html() + '</div>').dialog({
  ...
});
```

When you should be using it directly, unless you have a strong reason not to.

```
$('#editUser-' + id).dialog({
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Dialog **always creates a copy** of the HTML content and thus creates a repeated element with the same Id.

Using this selector `$("#avatarWarper-"+id)` will only obtain the element present when the page loaded and not the one dynamically created by the dialog.

I just had the same issue with Fancybox. My only solution was to use a class selector instead or `div[id="theid"]`